# ЧПУ в Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

Чтобы задать ЧПУ в Joomla 1.5, htaccess.txt был переименован в .htaccess, и подключен модуль mod_rewrite
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylAJW.png
После этого главная страница сайта, она же - пункт меню по умолчанию, открывается, а другие страницы, ссылки на который приобрели вид http://puck/products , не открывается, браузер выдает

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

puck
02/08/13 20:18:33
Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8u

Сайт лежит на локальном сервере (openserver), кэш джумлы был почищен.
Как решить эту проблему?

**UPD** В опенсервере mod rewrite я, так понимаю, есть,
в phpinfo выдается в Loaded Modules среди прочего mod_rewrite

Если я просто переименовываю .htaccess и в Общих настройках задаю Включить mod_rewrite, то ссылки имеют старый вид http://puck/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48&Itemid=56
но на страницы зайти можно,
как только я включаю SEO - да,
сразу появляется вот эта ошибка при заходе на страницы.
В чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в .htaccess расскоментировать:

`# RewriteBase /`

Comment: не, не помогло